# Select random parameter captured using Ord=All

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

How to select a random parameter captured using

```
web_reg_save_param("varParamName",
                   "LB=value=\"",
                   "RB=\"",
                   "Ord=All",
                   LAST);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LB and RB conditions are too generic.  Pick something more specific to what you are trying to capture

To your greater question, there are several paths on picking an ordinal depending upon your version of LoadRunner.    Something which works for every version would be

```
char foo[50];
...
sprintf(
     foo,
     "{varParamName_%d}",
     rand() * atoi( lr_eval_string("{varParamName_count}" ) ) +1
);
...
lr_save_string(
     lr_eval_string( foo ), 
     "LR_MyRandomCorrelatedvariable"
);
    ...
lr_output_message(
     "%s", 
     lr_eval_string( "{LR_MyRandomCorrelatedvariable}" ) 
);
```

Comment: Well yes I did pick a more specific boundary. That was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

to randomize the correlation values we can use ***lr_paramarr_random*** function.

web_reg_save_param("varParamName","LB=value=\"","RB=\"","Ord=All",LAST);

// some request ***web_submit_form()

//Save a randomly selected ID to a Parameter
 lr_save_string(lr_paramarr_random("varParamName"),"RandomParam");

now we can use RandomParam instead of varParamName. it will provide random values.